# What type of plastic can be used to produce your own filament?

Tags: filament-production, filament-quality

I'm considering purchasing Filabot or some similar filament maker.

What kind of plastic can I use to produce my own filament? Can I use any type of plastic or just specific printable filaments? <strike>Can I also mix different types of filament together or only one type at a time?</strike>

Comment: This question seems overly broad. "Can I produce filament from plastic X?" is a better, more focused question than "What plastics can be used to produce filaments?". Moreover, you have 3 separate questions in a single post, it's better to have a single question per post.

Comment: While I agree there are too many questions, "Can I produce filament from plastic X?" may not be possible for the OP. Not everyone is familiar with material names. So, in this case, a generalized answer might be acceptable. I don't know, however, if this hinders the scope of the site.

Comment: I think this looks like the beginning of a good, general question. But right now, it is not just one, but *three* questions. I would suggest that the OP would focus on only one question to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filament manufacturers (for example, Colorfabb) also sell pellets, price per kilo would be about 10 times less than the same plastic in filament form.

Out of household garbage only ABS can be easily extruded into filament with Filabot-grade machine. PET AKA plastic bottles looks promising as well.

You can also use certain products "off-label". For example, string trimmer string (line) is simply a nylon filament and can be used as-is in modern diameter-agnostic hot end.

Comment: This question is rather broad, but your answer is rather narrow. I'm sure far more types of plastic could be used.

Comment: the price per kilo would be 1/10th the cost, not ten times less, although this comment may belong in the language SE section.